# Converting strstream to sstream conflict about c_str()

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, sstream, c-str, strstream

I have this code block as written with `strstream`. And I converted it to `sstream` as below. I'm not sure, but I think `printStream->str()` is returning a string object with a copy (temporary) of the contents in the stream buffer pointed by `printStream`, and then then you are invoking `c_str()` on it and getting a `const char *`, and then casting away the const-ness, and then returning the pointer outside the function scope.  I think since its a temporary value you are getting back from `printStream->str()`, you will be using a pointer to deallocated memory outside this function. How should I do this?

```
char * FieldData::to_string() const
{
  if(printStream)
    return printStream->str();
  FieldData* notConst = (FieldData*) this;
  notConst->printStream = new std::ostrstream;
  // check heap sr60315556
  if (notConst->printStream == NULL)
    return NULL;
  *(notConst->printStream) << "Invalid Field Type";
  *(notConst->printStream) << '\0';
  return printStream->str();
}

char * FieldData::to_string() const
{
  if(printStream)
    return const_cast<char *>(printStream->str().c_str());
  FieldData* notConst = (FieldData*) this;
  notConst->printStream = new std::ostringstream;
  // check heap sr60315556
  if (notConst->printStream == NULL)
    return NULL;
  *(notConst->printStream) << "Invalid Field Type";
  *(notConst->printStream) << '\0';
  return const_cast<char *>(printStream->str().c_str());
}
```

Comment: Don't use `new`, don't use C-style casts, don't use `const_cast` *especially* to modify the variable, don't use C-style strings, don't return pointers to memory that's already deallocated. In fact, I'm fairly sure if it would be easier to start anew than fix this code.

Comment: for example how should i  change my code ?                                          return const_cast<char *>(printStream->str().c_str());

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type to `std::string` and return a `std::string` object directly.

Comment: how should i do ? for example, how can i change this line                     
 return const_cast<char *>(printStream->str().c_str());

Answer (score 1):

I think a function called `to_string` really, really, *really* should return a `std::string`.

And then all this junk can be replaced by

```
std::string FieldData::to_string() const
{ return "Invalid Field Type"; }
```